# Press NumLock without NumLock-Key?

Tags: numlock

I have an external USB Numberpad, that has no <kbd>NumLock</kbd> key itself. Since my Laptop hasn't one either I have no way to disable NumLock if it is set.

Now the Numberpad is set to NumLock and I can only access the arrows, PgUp... on it.

How can I change the NumLock state to write numbers again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start the [Onboard Keyboard](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/onboard/) there you click on the Numberpad-Button <kbd>123</kbd> where you have a <kbd>NumLock</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can install the package `gkrellm-leds` (available directly in Synaptic).

This will also install gkrellm system monitor that provides a lot of information about your computer. You can disable everything that you do not need, keeping only the leds for numlock, capslock and scrollock. By clicking with your mouse on the leds you can change the status of the keyboard. And you can stick this small window anywhere on the desktop and launch it at starting. A really nice little program that you can custom by choosing amongst over 190 display themes.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a shortcut that runs `numlockx`.

Install `numlockx` by running:

```
sudo apt install numlockx
```

Then you can add a shortcut (use the shortcut manager of your desktop environment) to toggle the NumLock state by binding the following command:

```
numlockx toggle
```